# Change Data Factory Window Timezone

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an activity in a pipeline that needs to run at 2am Sydney Time, and select timeslice data from 2am the previous day up until 2am the run date.

02:00 sydney is 15:00 UTC, so I specified in my datasets and pipelines

```
"availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1,
        "offset":"15:00:00"
    },
```

And I have a select query in a copy activity

```
"oracleReaderQuery": "`$`$Text.Format('select * FROM table WHERE juliandate  >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(\\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}\\',\\'YYYY-MM-DD\\'), \\'YYYYDDD\\'))-1900000 and juliandate < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(\\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd}\\',\\'YYYY-MM-DD\\'), \\'YYYYDDD\\'))-1900000', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"
```

Now the pipeline seems to run at the correct time of 2am, however, the window date passed to the query seems to still be in UTC - see the run below for the 1st March at 2am

[image]

I could fix this I guess by adding in the 11 hours in the query itself, but it seems a bit of a workaround - and there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

What you changed is the time when it will be run, but that doesnt make data factory use another timezone. WindowStart and WindowEnd in your query will always be in UTC, you can vote for the idea to change timezones here, but the idea has been around since 2015 and most people fix it by adding hours: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/10879920-allow-setting-the-timezone-for-slices

You can use some of these functions to get what you want here (most likely AddHours(X,Y) ): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-functions-variables#data-factory-functions

Hope this helped!